# C++ boost::regex multiples captures

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to recover multiples substrings thanks to boost::regex and put each one in a var. Here my code :

```
unsigned int i = 0;
std::string string = "--perspective=45.0,1.33,0.1,1000";
std::string::const_iterator start = string.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = string.end();
std::vector<std::string> matches;
boost::smatch what;
boost::regex const ex(R"(^-?\d*\.?\d+),(^-?\d*\.?\d+),(^-?\d*\.?\d+),(^-?\d*\.?\d+))");

string.resize(4);

while (boost::regex_search(start, end, what, ex)
{
    std::string stest(what[1].first, what[1].second);
    matches[i] = stest;
    start = what[0].second;
    ++i;
}
```

I'm trying to extract each float of my string and put it in my vector variable matches. My result, at the moment, is that I can extract the first one (in my vector var, I can see "45" without double quotes) but the second one in my vector var is empty (matches[1] is "").

I can't figure out why and how to correct this. So my question is how to correct this ? Is my regex not correct ? My smatch incorrect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, `^` is symbol for the beginning of a line. Secondly, `\` must be escaped. So you  should fix each `(^-?\d*\.?\d+)` group to `(-?\\d*\\.\\d+)`. (Probably, `(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)` is better.)
2. Your regular expression searches for the `number,number,number,number` pattern, not for the each number. You add only the first substring to `matches` and ignore others. To fix this, you can replace your expression with `(-?\\d*\\.\\d+)` or just add all the matches stored in `what` to your `matches` vector:

```cpp
 while (boost::regex_search(start, end, what, ex))
 {
      for(int j = 1; j < what.size(); ++j) 
      { 
           std::string stest(what[j].first, what[j].second);
           matches.push_back(stest);
      }
      start = what[0].second;
 }
```

Comment: I changed my regex for this : R"(^--perspective=(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+))"); but with your solution, my first var contain all the string instade of the first float. Do you know why ?

Comment: @LaurentD. By adding the parens to the beginning and to the end, you groupped all the expression. Try: `R"(?:^--perspective=(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+))"` or `R"^--perspective=(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+)"` instead. Remember, every paren is important in regular expressions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `^` at several times in your regex. That's why it didn't match. `^` means the beginning of the string. Also you have an extra `)` at the end of the regex. I don't know that closing bracket doing there.

Here is your regex after correction:

```
(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+),(-?\d*\.?\d+)
```

A better version of your regex can be(only if you want to avoid matching numbers like `.01`, `.1`):

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Answer (score 0):

A repeated search in combination with a regular expression that apparently is built to match all of the target string is pointless.

If you are searching repeatedly in a moving window delimited by a moving iterator and `string.end()` then you should reduce the pattern to something that matches a single fraction.

If you know that the number of fractions in your string is/must be constant, match once, not in a loop and extract the matched substrings from `what`.